# Adding PORTAL Inside a TAB PANEL in EXTJS : Using the Portal Demo by EXTJS

Tags: javascript, tabs, extjs4, portal

I am currently using EXTjs's default Portal Demo.. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/extjs-build/examples/portal/portal.html

Can anyone tell me if we can make a Centered TabPanel which has say 3 tabs, and each tab has a Portal inside.

So on the page load, we are on Tab 1.. Which essentially is a Portal where I can drag and drop things around. Same for Tab 2.

Inside of the portal.js provided by ExtJs, we have code for creating the `portalpanel`. 
Everything works, but now I have to have a Tabpanel instead of a portal panel, essentially, portalpanel inside a tabpanel.

The code with which the `portalpanel` is displayed is :

```
 Ext.define('Ext.app.Portal', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    uses: ['Ext.app.PortalPanel', 'Ext.app.PortalColumn', 'Ext.app.GridPortlet', 'Ext.app.ChartPortlet'],
    initComponent: function(){
var content = '<div class="portlet-content">'+Ext.s.shortBogusMarkup+'</div>';
        Ext.apply(this, {
            id: 'app-viewport',
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                padding: '0 5 5 5'
            },
            items: [{
                id: 'app-header',
                xtype: 'box',
                region: 'north',
                height: 40,
                html: '<div></div>'
            },{
                xtype: 'container',
                region: 'center',
                layout: 'border',
                items: [{
                    id: 'app-options',
                    title: 'All Widgets',
                    region: 'west',
                    animCollapse: true,
                    width: 200,
                    minWidth: 150,
                    maxWidth: 400,
                    split: true,
                    collapsible: true,
                    layout: 'accordion',
                    layoutConfig:{
                        animate: true
                    },
                    items: [{
                        html: '<div class="portlet-content">'+Ext.s.example+'</div>',
                        title:'Tables',
                        autoScroll: true,
                        border: false,
                        iconCls: 'nav'
                    },
               {
                    id: 'app-portal',
                    xtype: 'portalpanel',
                    region: 'center',
                    items: [{
                        id: 'col-1',
                        items: [{
                            id: 'portlet-1',
                            title: 'Grid Portlet',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            items: Ext.create('Ext.app.GridPortlet'),
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        },{
                            id: 'portlet-2',
                            title: 'Portlet 2',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            html: content,
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        }]
                    },{
                        id: 'col-2',
                        items: [{
                            id: 'portlet-3',
                            title: 'Portlet 3',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            html: '<div class="portlet-content">'+Ext.smartdashboard.bogusMarkup+'</div>',
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        }]
                    },{
                        id: 'col-3',
                        items: [{
                            id: 'portlet-4',
                            title: 'Stock Portlet',
                            tools: this.getTools(),
                            items: Ext.create('Ext.app.ChartPortlet'),
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                }
```

Any ideas folks if we can somehow create a `portalpanel` inside a `tabpanel`(using the existing portal example)
`Please help!!!!`

Answer (score 1):

ur using ajax tab in ajas tab ur call url ,in that url ur displayed portal panel like below code

```
            var tabs2 = Ext.widget('tabpanel', {
                renderTo: document.body,
                activeTab: 0,
                width: 600,
                height: 250,
                plain: true,
                defaults :{
                    autoScroll: true,
                    bodyPadding: 10
                },
                items: [{
                        title: 'Normal Tab',
                        html: "My content was added during construction."
                    },{
                        title: 'Ajax Tab 1',
                        loader: {
                            url: 'ajax1.htm',
                            contentType: 'html',
                            loadMask: true
                        },
                        listeners: {
                            activate: function(tab) {
                                tab.loader.load();
                            }
                        }
                    },{
                        title: 'Ajax Tab 2',
                        loader: {
                            url: 'ajax2.htm',
                            contentType: 'html',
                            autoLoad: true,
                            params: 'foo=123&bar=abc'
                        }
                    },{
                        title: 'Event Tab',
                        listeners: {
                            activate: function(tab){
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    alert(tab.title + ' was activated.');
                                }, 1);
                            }
                        },
                        html: "I am tab 4's content. I also have an event listener attached."
                    },{
                        title: 'Disabled Tab',
                        disabled: true,
                        html: "Can't see me cause I'm disabled"
                    }
                ]
            });
```

Comment: Hi ravi, thank you for the answer. Could you please tell me if the `ajax1.htm`,etc.. in that `html` page.. I will be calling another JS which has a `portalpanel` inside? 
I do not see any portalpanel in the code you gave. That's why I am confused.
Actually I have create Tabs on the fly, and portal's inside of those tabs's on the fly as well.
I would really appreciate if you could provide `some code` for the call for portalpanel inside the ajax1.htm.

Comment: hi First Blood , first ur give ur total code and i will tell which place u will modifies , but i am told logic of ur question ok ,ur portal panel displayed in atabpanel ,am i right?

Comment: Hi ravi, thanks again. I have `updated my code` . But therez really nothing, it's just making a Portal at the start. Actually I want to retain all the functionality which is present in the http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/extjs-build/examples/portal/portal.html demo, and instead of the Center 4 Portlets, I just want Tabs instead, and each tab should have those 4 portlets in them! Thanks again :)

Comment: I am making an ajax call when a tab is clicked, and that calls the JS which has this code : 
`Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
width: '50%',
height: 500,
items: [{
title: 'TabPanel'
}]
})`
Just to see if it actually loads.. So it works now..
But if I have to replace that with portalpanel, how can I do that? any clues? 
My ajax call looks like this : 
`{
title: 'Ajax Tab 2',
loader: {
url: '/static/javascript/dashboard/tabPortal.js',
renderer: 'component',
loadMask: true
}`
Also I want to avoid duplicates after 1st ajax call, since A new tab panel is created afta 1st call. 
Thanks.

Comment: `{ title: 'Ajax Tab 2', loader: { url: '/static/javascript/dashboard/tabPortal.html', renderer: 'component', loadMask: true }`                                                                                  in that place ur using .js file but ur use .html file ur create a new  html file ur tabportal.js is inculed in that html file that html file is add in loader url

Comment: Hi Ravi, actually I can call the JS and it renders perfectly fine, but is it possible to attach a code snippet or something like what should be the tabPortal.js look like? Which has tabportal and portalpanels in each tab? If you could attach a snippet, I'd be grateful. 
As of now I am constrained to use just this.. only as a working example.. 
`Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
 width: '50%',
 height: 500,
 items: [{
 title: 'TabPanel'
 }]
})`
Does it really matter if I call Html instead of JS? Because it still is rendering correctly.
Thanks once again.

Comment: Hey Ravi, Just an update, that I figured out a way to use the existing Portal example and tweaked it to have accordion on the left, tabpanel having portalpanel and portlets in the middle.. My only problem now is, for some reason the `Tabs` are not showing up.. the tabs are rendered.. But they are not shown on the screen, so I can't really click and play around.. My problem is almost solved, but don't know if this is an existing bug out here
`{
id: 'tab-portal', 
xtype: 'tabpanel',        
activeTab: 0,
region: 'center',
items: [{`
{
title: 'tab2',
html: 'YEEE1',
 closable: true
},
}
^ For Ex.